# destruction of container of trival objects

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a simple struct that has a pointer and an int inside it:

```
struct A
{
    int* ptr_;
    int  i_;
};
```

I now create a vector of these structs :

```
std::vector<A> vec_;
```

Now A's destructor has nothing to do. So when vec_ is destructed, will the compiler still emit calls to A's destructor?

Comment: Maybe. It's up to your compiler.

Comment: How would you tell if it did?

Comment: @aschepler view disassembly